# Windows Phone 8 http post file upload timeout

Tags: http, file-upload, windows-phone-8, amazon-s3, timeout

I am developing a Windows phone 8 app that needs to upload photos to amazon s3 storage. However, I find that this is impossible since the HttpClient time out after about 60 seconds regardless of what timeout setting I use.

Is there really no way to upload large files from Windows Phone?

BackgroundTransferRequest is useless since it cannot send the neccessary metadata with file uploads.

I use this code (which times out):

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, m_uploadUrl);
    httpContent.Headers.Add("Keep-Alive", "true");
    request.Content = httpContent; // 3-5 Mb file 
    response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    statusCode = response.StatusCode;
}
```

I also tried PostAsync(), but same result. After about 60 sec the call completes with a status code 400 or 404. This is not a server timeout. IPhone and Android apps use the same service. No problems there.

Any ideas on how to upload files that takes more than 60 seconds to send?

Answer (score 0):

I too faced similar things. The timeout glitch.
Check if you could use another class instead of HttpClient. 
WebClient may be.

Check if this helps you:
http://blog.anthonybaker.me/2013/06/how-to-upload-file-from-windows-phone.html

and even this:
http://chriskoenig.net/2011/08/19/upload-files-from-windows-phone/

I got things working for me with those.

Comment: I tried HttpWebRequest, but the same problem there. As soon as i trottle bandwidth, the request failes after 60 seconds.

Comment: Even i had done things with the HttpWebRequest. Fiddled a lot. Same issue. Timeout. Exactly. I even had a class with all possible http communication ways. :D . Post with all ways, even synchronous and asynchronous. Same problem. 
However, the above ways solved it out for me.

Comment: Thanks. The first link is no different than what I'm doing. I'll try the second one (WebClient) and see if that is any better

Comment: Have you looked at the Windows Phone 8 support in V2 of the AWS SDK for .NET?

Comment: Yes, but as far as I can see, then I will need to embed the secret key in the app to do that. Using http post, I don't need it since I have a policy and a signature.

Answer (score 0):

I've used several days now to implement a new uploader and get all the details working. I used HttpWebRequest with the async methods and split the file into chuncks. Finally I got it working and it uploads without the timeout. Here is the complete code:

```
using System;
using Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Services
{
    public class UploadData
    {
        public Stream PostStream { get; set; }
        public Stream FileStream { get; set; }
        public byte[] HeaderBytes {get; set;}
        public byte[] FooterBytes  {get; set;}
        public byte[] Buffer { get; set; }
        public Photo Upload { get; set; }
        public int BytesWritten { get; set; }
    }

    public class UploadEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public Photo Upload { get; set; }
        public int Progress { get; set; }
    }

    public class UploadService
    {
        public delegate void CompletedEventHandler(object sender, UploadEventArgs e);
        public event CompletedEventHandler UploadCompleted;
        public delegate void ProgressEventHandler(object sender, UploadEventArgs e);
        public event ProgressEventHandler ProgressChanged;

        private static string contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary={0}";
        private static string headerString = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"{0}\"\r\nContent-Type: Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n";
        private HttpWebRequest m_request;
        private static string boundarystr;

        private UploadData m_uploadData;
        private bool m_isStopped;

        public async Task StartUpload(Photo upload, Uri uri, Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
        {
            try
            {
                m_isStopped = false;
                var fileStream = (await upload.File.OpenReadAsync()).AsStreamForRead();

                var uploadData = new UploadData();

                boundarystr = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
                string para = GetParamsString(parameters);
                string headAndParams = para + String.Format(headerString, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(upload.File.Name));

                var headerBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(headAndParams);
                var footerBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundarystr + "--\r\n");

                uploadData.Upload = upload;
                uploadData.FileStream = fileStream;
                uploadData.FooterBytes = footerBytes;
                uploadData.HeaderBytes = headerBytes;
                uploadData.BytesWritten = 0;
                m_uploadData = uploadData;
                m_request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
                m_request.Method = "POST";
                m_request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
                m_request.ContentType = string.Format(contentType, boundarystr);
                m_request.ContentLength = fileStream.Length + headerBytes.Length + footerBytes.Length;
                var asyncResult = m_request.BeginGetRequestStream((ar) => { GetRequestStreamCallback(ar, uploadData); }, m_request);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                m_uploadData.Upload.UploadInfo.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
                m_uploadData.Upload.UploadInfo.Exception = new Exception("Start upload failed: " + ex.Message);
                var argsStopped = new UploadEventArgs();
                argsStopped.Upload = m_uploadData.Upload;
                m_uploadData.FileStream.Close();
                m_uploadData.PostStream.Close();
                OnUploadComplete(argsStopped);
            }
        }

        private void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult, UploadData uploadData)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
                Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);

                postStream.Write(uploadData.HeaderBytes, 0, uploadData.HeaderBytes.Length);

                var args = new UploadEventArgs();
                args.Upload = uploadData.Upload;
                args.Progress = 1;
                OnProgressChanged(args);
                uploadData.PostStream = postStream;

                WriteNextChunck(uploadData);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                m_uploadData.Upload.UploadInfo.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
                m_uploadData.Upload.UploadInfo.Exception = new Exception("Header write failed: " + ex.Message);
                var argsStopped = new UploadEventArgs();
                argsStopped.Upload = m_uploadData.Upload;
                m_uploadData.FileStream.Close();
                m_uploadData.PostStream.Close();
                OnUploadComplete(argsStopped);
            }
        }

        private void WriteNextChunck(UploadData upload)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((upload.FileStream.Length - upload.BytesWritten) >= 16 * 1024)
                {
                    upload.Buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
                }
                else
                {
                    // Last part
                    upload.Buffer = new byte[upload.FileStream.Length - upload.BytesWritten];
                }

                upload.FileStream.Read(upload.Buffer, 0, (int)upload.Buffer.Length);
                upload.PostStream.BeginWrite(upload.Buffer, 0, upload.Buffer.Length, BeginWriteCallback, upload);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                m_uploadData.Upload.UploadInfo.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
                m_uploadData.Upload.UploadInfo.Exception = new Exception("Buffer write failed: " + ex.Message);
                var argsStopped = new UploadEventArgs();
                argsStopped.Upload = m_uploadData.Upload;
                upload.FileStream.Close();
                upload.PostStream.Close();
                OnUploadComplete(argsStopped);
            }
        }

        private void BeginWriteCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                var upload = ar.AsyncState as UploadData;
                upload.PostStream.EndWrite(ar);
                upload.BytesWritten += upload.Buffer.Length;

                var args = new UploadEventArgs();
                args.Upload = upload.Upload;
                args.Progress = (int)(((decimal)upload.BytesWritten / (decimal)upload.FileStream.Length) * 100);
                OnProgressChanged(args);

                if (m_isStopped)
                {
                    upload.FileStream.Close();
                    upload.PostStream.Close();
                    m_uploadData.Upload.UploadInfo.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
                    m_uploadData.Upload.UploadInfo.Exception = new Exception("Upload stopped");
                    var argsStopped = new UploadEventArgs();
                    argsStopped.Upload = m_uploadData.Upload;
                    OnUploadComplete(argsStopped);
                    return;
                }

                // write next chunck
                if (upload.BytesWritten < upload.FileStream.Length)
                {
                    WriteNextChunck(upload);
                }
                if (upload.BytesWritten >= upload.FileStream.Length)
                {
                    WriteFooter(upload);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                m_uploadData.Upload.UploadInfo.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
                m_uploadData.Upload.UploadInfo.Exception = new Exception("Upload write failed: " + ex.Message);
                var argsStopped = new UploadEventArgs();
                argsStopped.Upload = m_uploadData.Upload;
                OnUploadComplete(argsStopped);
            }
        }

        private void WriteFooter(UploadData upload)
        {
            try
            {
                upload.PostStream.Write(upload.FooterBytes, 0, upload.FooterBytes.Length);
                upload.PostStream.Close();
                var asyncResult = m_request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), m_request);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                m_uploadData.Upload.UploadInfo.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
                m_uploadData.Upload.UploadInfo.Exception = new Exception("Footer write failed: " + ex.Message);
                var argsStopped = new UploadEventArgs();
                argsStopped.Upload = m_uploadData.Upload;
                OnUploadComplete(argsStopped);
            }
        }

        private void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
                Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
                string responseString = streamRead.ReadToEnd();
                streamResponse.Close();
                streamRead.Close();
                response.Close();

                m_uploadData.FileStream.Close();
                m_uploadData.Upload.UploadInfo.StatusCode = response.StatusCode;

                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NoContent)
                {
                    m_uploadData.Upload.UploadInfo.Exception = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    m_uploadData.Upload.UploadInfo.Exception = new Exception(responseString);
                }
                var args = new UploadEventArgs();
                args.Upload = m_uploadData.Upload;
                args.Progress = 100;
                OnUploadComplete(args);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                m_uploadData.Upload.UploadInfo.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
                m_uploadData.Upload.UploadInfo.Exception = ex;
                var args = new UploadEventArgs();
                args.Upload = m_uploadData.Upload;
                OnUploadComplete(args);
            }
        }  

        private string GetParamsString(Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
        {
            bool needsCLRF = false;
            string result = "";
            foreach (var param in parameters)
            {
                // Thanks to feedback from commenters, add a CRLF to allow multiple parameters to be added.
                // Skip it on the first parameter, add it to subsequent parameters.
                if (needsCLRF)
                    result += "\r\n";

                needsCLRF = true;

                string prm = string.Format("--{0}\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name={1}\r\n\r\n{2}",
                        boundarystr,
                        param.Key,
                        param.Value);
                result += prm;

            }

            // Add the end of the request.  Start with a newline
            string footer = "\r\n--" + boundarystr + "\r\n";
            result += footer;

            return result;
        }

        protected virtual void OnUploadComplete(UploadEventArgs e)
        {
            if (UploadCompleted != null)
                UploadCompleted(this, e);
        }

        protected virtual void OnProgressChanged(UploadEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ProgressChanged != null)
                ProgressChanged(this, e);
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            m_isStopped = true;
        }

    }
}
```